# Validate value of property in flutter that isn't a TextFormField

Tags: validation, flutter, conditional-statements

this is the first question that I'm producing on StackOverFlow so I'm going to do my best to be as clear and concise as possible.

I'm attempting to validate a field within a `DateTimePicker` in flutter to essentially change the color of the button to red and display an error to the user if a time hasn't been chosen when the submit button is clicked. The only solutions that I've come across have been related to `TextFormField` validation and input validation. Since the output produced from the `DateTimePicker` IS NOT a `TextFormField` and I don't have access to the validator function, I'm trying to come up with a solution that will allow for me to still validate the `startTime` selection upon click of the submit button.

One solution that I came up with was to wrap my `_buildStartEndButtons` function in an if statement, which returns a red button if the `startTime` value is null and black if a time has been selected. However, this doesn't address my issue of displaying the error to the user ONLY if the submit button has been clicked and the user hasn't entered anything. My current solution doesn't make for a very friendly user experience. I'm simply having a difficult time trying to wrap my head around how to pass the state of my `startTime` property to my submit button.

Menu Model Widget:

```
class MenuModel {
  String startTime;
  String endTime;
}
```

Hours Widget:

```
  class DateTimePicker extends StatelessWidget {
  MenuModel menu;
  Function updateStartTime;
  Function updateEndTime;

  DateTimePicker(
    this.menu,
    this.updateStartTime,
    this.updateEndTime,
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15, vertical: 15),
          child: Text(
            'What are the hours?',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15, vertical: 15),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              _buildTimeRange(
                  starts: this.menu.startTime, ends: this.menu.endTime),
              _buildStartEndButtons(context),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );

  Container _buildStartEndButtons(BuildContext context) {
    String errorMsg = 'Please select a time';

    if (this.menu.startTime == null) {
      return Container(
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: RaisedButton(
                color: Colors.red,
                onPressed: () {
                  DatePicker.showTimePicker(context,
                      theme: DatePickerTheme(containerHeight: 200.0),
                      showTitleActions: true, onConfirm: (time) {
                    print('confirm $time');
                    this.updateStartTime('${time.hour} : ${time.minute}');
                  }, currentTime: DateTime.now(), locale: LocaleType.en);
                },
                child: Text(
                  'Starts',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                ),
              ),
            ),
    } else {
      return Container(
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: RaisedButton(
                color: Colors.black,
                onPressed: () {
                  DatePicker.showTimePicker(context,
                      theme: DatePickerTheme(containerHeight: 200.0),
                      showTitleActions: true, onConfirm: (time) {
                    print('confirm $time');
                    this.updateStartTime('${time.hour} : ${time.minute}');
                  }, currentTime: DateTime.now(), locale: LocaleType.en);
                },
                child: Text(
                  'Starts',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
    }
  }
  Container _buildTimeRange({String starts, String ends}) {
    if (starts == null || starts.isEmpty) {
      starts = '';
    }
    if (ends == null || ends.isEmpty) {
      ends = '';
    }

    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
        children: <Widget>[
          Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                child: Text(
                  'Starts',
                  style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                child: Text(
                  starts,
                  style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                child: Text(
                  'Ends',
                  style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                child: Text(
                  ends,
                  style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

AddMenuView Widget:

```
class AddMenuView extends StatefulWidget {
  AddMenuView({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  _AddMenuViewState createState() => _AddMenuViewState();
}
class _AddMenuViewState extends State<AddMenuView> {
  MenuModel menu;

 void updateStartTime(String start) {   
    setState(() {
      this.menu.startTime = start;
    });
  }

return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Restaurant Information'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white54),
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15, vertical: 15),
        child: (Column(children: <Widget>[

      Container(
            child: DateTimePicker(menu, updateStartTime, updateEndTime),
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              boxShadow: [
                BoxShadow(
                  color: color,
                ),
              ],
              border: Border.all(color: Colors.black),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                Radius.circular(25.0),
              ),
            ),
          ),

      FlatButton(
            color: Colors.black,
            child: Text(
              'Submit',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              this.menu.startTime.isEmpty ? print('Value needed') : print('Value exists');
         },
          )
        ])),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

SideNote: Disregard the `endTime` property for now. I'm simply breaking it down to come up with a solution for the `startTime` property on StackOverFlow so that I can figure out the second piece of my problem on my own.

Thank you guys for taking the time to help me out and if it isn't totally clear on what I'm trying to accomplish here please ask and I'll do my best to elaborate further!

Comment: How about this? [flutter_datetime_formfield](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_datetime_formfield).

Comment: I thought about using a library and I will more than likely go with this as a last resort, but I really wanted to push myself to come up with my own custom functions as well as reduce the amount of dependencies utilized in the app.